# Update DataGridView from thread

Tags: database, multithreading, datagridview

So I have simple DataGridView with rows containing name, surname, status.

Now I have another sub which is starting 5 threads. Each thread will do it's job and update DGV accordingly to its result.

Problem is that to run thread accessing update method for DGV I had to set:

```
_namethread= New Thread(AddressOf namethread)
_namethread.IsBackground = True
_namethread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
```

With set STA I end up without errors BUT DGV isn't updated and nothing happens. It looks like call for update method simple is skipping (on update method I do have Application.DoEvents just in case)

There is also another thing. I want to use threads to update database, refresh DGV for other tables, etc.

Thing is that I know how to access textboxes from threads (by delegating method) but I have no idea how to do it with accessing database by SQL query or even DHV to show progress.

Maybe I should use event riser or something else.

How are you doing this normally :) ? 
If I'm correct if I would create custom Event, I could call it from thread ?

Is this DoEvents working like other subs (so it would go step by step through all events rised, so for example would update 6 records in database ?)

Something like a queue ?

I just need to know in which direction I should go with threads (as I want do to very heavily multithreaded application)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this issue by using delegates.